# Output form option for symbolic or decimal form

Tags: output-formatting

How do I set up a function's options so that the function returns its results in either the exact form (default) or with N decimal places?

Comment: Read the docs on `N`

Answer (score 2):

```
fun[x_, r_Integer: 0] := 
    x + 1 // If[r == 0, #, N[#, Length@IntegerDigits@IntegerPart@# + r]] &

fun[1]
```

> 2

```
fun[1, 4]
```

> 2.0000

```
fun[1/2]
```

> 3/2

```
fun[1/2, 1]
```

> 1.5

If you need this also for other functions you could define

```
rounder[x_, 0] := x
rounder[x_, r_] := N[x, Length@IntegerDigits@IntegerPart@x + r]
```

and now simply

```
foo[x_, r_Integer: 0] := rounder[x + 2, r]
```